# Error with INSERT QUERY from python script to insert data into MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

water = {}
water['time'] = 1500379234.16
water['resistance'] = 18.20
water['temperature'] = 21.9
water['time'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(water['time']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #imports to datetime 

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "monitor", "password","WQMS_database")
curs = db.cursor()

curs.execute ("INSERT INTO water_data values(water['time'], water['resistance'], water['temperature'])")
```

**Error message:**

```
mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your 
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near '['time'],
water['resistance'], water['temperature']' at line 1")
```

The fields in the database are `datetime`, `float` and `float` respectively.

Comment: I can't understand what your script should do? what does water['anything'] means?

Comment: why are u using `water['time']` ... try just water_time

Comment: `curs.execute("INSERT INTO water_data  VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))`

Comment: the python existing script uses this. This script shown is just a simplified version so we can understand how to query the data into the water_data table in the database. 

i attempted what you said mwweb which seemed to get rid of the error message however when executing it states 1L (which i have no idea what it means) and when checking the database there is no entry...

Comment: If you're using mysql, then why did you tag sql server?

Comment: @SMor if he's using Python why did he tag PHP?

Answer (score 0):

`water['time']` is not interpolated as you expected.
Parameterize your variables like this:

```
curs.execute ("INSERT INTO water_data values(%s, %s, %s)", (water['time'], water['resistance'], water['temperature']))
```